# Are parameter annotations prohibited in overridden methods?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

I came across the problem that my code didn't work when I had the following case. I had an interface where some methods were defined. One of them is like this.

```
@javax.ws.rs.POST
Response post(@javax.ws.rs.QueryParam("someParam") final java.lang.String someParam);
```

So, I needed to implement it and I went to my implementation class, Intellij IDEA highlighted that I am missing some methods and by help of Intellij IDEA I generated the basic signature of the method which was like this:

```
@Override
public Response post(@QueryParam("someParam") String someParam) {
    return null;
}
```

Then I was struggling with the error *HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed* which Jetty was returning when I was trying to call this method. Finally the solution was that I didn't need the `@QueryParam("someParam")` in my overridden method.

1. *Is it very specific case or I am not allowed to include any annotations to the parameters in the overridden method?*
2. *Does Intellij IDEA generate it wrong and it is a bug?*

Comment: This kind of method is called by the Jetty Container when getting http request. I do not think it should be called by you unless you are overriding default Jetty Container behaviour. The annotation @QueryParam("someParam") means to get the value of key named someParam from URL and attach the value to variable String someParam

Comment: Why are you calling this -- it's supposed to be called by the container. Is it a test? You shouldn't have an interface for this. Also, everything like this is much much much easier with spring than with jee.

Comment: No, it is not a test, but I am trying to get familiar with YaaS platform which offers the template project together with Jetty and it seems that the logic should be exactly there. Thus, yes, it I override the Jetty Container behavior, but it is intentional.